# Disable events on element to be handled by underlying element

Tags: html, css

I'm making an app where I have a map which can be controlled using mouse events and a div overlay over that map to display informations.

The thing is, with the overlay div is over my map, I lose the control of the map (event are registered by the overlay not by the map underneath).

I tried applying the CSS property `pointer-events: none` to my overlay but this doesn't work.

I've setup a working example illustrating the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/oj3nkxm72q

Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: You cannot use mouse events on map if there is an overlay. However, you can achieve that using javascript. Track mouse events on the overlay and apply them on the map `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it works for you.
For overlay class give css position:absolute; and z-index:2;,
for mapboxgl-map class make the z-index:1; instead of -1;

Comment: but it's working on the link you send just added .mapboxgl-canvas{z-index:1 !important} in your css and on line 30 for overlay class added z-index:2; position:absolute;